# Send searchParam data from one Component to another component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have one Component which shows a list of data in a dropdown and there is an option to search these data which works as a filter. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import Popover from '../../Popover';
import Input from '../../Input';
import Icon from '../../Icon';
import IconButton from '../../IconButton';

const DropDownFilter = props => {
  const { label, options, onChange, isSearchEnabled } = props;
  const [activeOption, setActiveOption] = useState({});
  const [filter, setfilter] = useState('');

  const searchFilter = event => {
    setfilter(event.target.value);
  };

  const removeFilter = () => {
    setfilter('');
  };

  const lowercasedFilter = filter.toLowerCase();
  const filteredData = options.filter(item => {
    return Object.keys(item).some(
      key => typeof item[key] === 'string' && item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
    );
  });

  const labelText = activeOption.label ? activeOption.label : label;

  const handleSelectedOption = option => {
    setActiveOption(option);
    onChange(option);
  };

  return (
    <div className="filter">
      <Popover linkText={labelText} size="small" direction="bottom-left">
        {isSearchEnabled && (
          <div className="filter__search">
            <Input
              value={filter}
              onChange={searchFilter}
              preIcon={
                <div role="presentation">
                  <Icon name="search" />
                </div>
              }
              placeholder="Search"
              postIcon={
                filter.length > 0 && (
                  <IconButton
                    icon={<Icon name="close" />}
                    size="tiny"
                    onClick={removeFilter}
                    standalone={true}
                    isIconOnly={true}
                  />
                )
              }
            />
          </div>
        )}
        <ul className="filter__options filter__options--scrollbar">
          {filteredData.map(option => (
            <li
              key={option.value}
              role="presentation"
              className={classNames('filter__options-option', {
                'filter__options-option--active': option.value === activeOption.value,
              })}
              onClick={() => handleSelectedOption(option)}
            >
              {option.label}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
};

DropDownFilter.defaultProps = {
  label: 'Filter Menu',
  options: [],
  isSearchEnabled: true,
};

DropDownFilter.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.node]),
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      label: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.node]),
      value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
    })
  ),
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isSearchEnabled: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default DropDownFilter;
```

Here is a gif of it: https://recordit.co/HtalUtuPsj

Now during searching I want to send the value of the search param to another component, the value will be used to search from a DB or any other external data source which is being handled in that new component. Such as, if I am searching for `Ratings`, this component should search for it in the existing options list it has in its own component, as well as the same time it will search for `Ratings` in any other external data source or DB. This external network call, search or any other functionality will be processed in the other component. So this component will only send the search param; for example `Ratings` to the other component in real time.

I can think of an idea like I will get the searchParam in a state and pass the setState value to a new props which will be called through an onSearchParamChange function, this new function will pass the data through a callback and the other component will get the data through calling that props of this component. I am not sure if this is the correct way and also I am not able to implement this thought in the code either. Is there any better way to do it? if so what would be that coding implementation?

Comment: Is the other component a parent component or a child component?

Comment: @jamomani It can be both. But mostly will be a parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass to a parent component you should be able to use for example the `onChange` prop which is passed to your component, like you are doing in the `handleSelectedOption` function. That function is in fact passing the chosen option to the parent component. If you want to pass to the parent component when the user is typing, then you should call the `onChange` function also in `searchFilter`:

```
  const searchFilter = event => {
    const option = event.target.value);
    setfilter(option);
    onChange(option);
  };
```

If you want to pass it to a child component, the you can just pass it as prop:

```
<ChildComponent filter={ filter } />
```

Comment: is this ```const searchFilter = event => {
    const option = event.target.value);
    setfilter(option);
    onChange(option);
  };```
change enough to pass the search param to the parent component? I was thinking to introduce a props in this component which will take the searchParam and pass that to the Parent Component . So that in the parent component when I use this component I will get the searchParam in the props and then use the value I get in the props for further search in the DB or another data source. Can this be done in the current codebase? if yes then how?

Comment: I don’t know exactly what the parent does with that onChange prop, but it looks like it is a callback function meant to pass the chosen option from child to parent. For what I can say I think it does what you need.

Comment: Will the parent get the desired search param from the child if it uses this onChange prop? Or do I need to introduce a new prop like onSearchChange and pass the search param there and use that new prop to get the param in the parent.

Comment: could you please answer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537302/open-a-specific-tab-by-matching-the-browser-url-and-tab-url. Thank you

Comment: Hi, I will have a look. If you found this answer useful, please mark it, so that other people will know it too.